# Use second hard disk for database if first one is full

Tags: sql-server, disk-space

I installed Standard Edition on a server with a 500 GB drive. Now the system is giving me error message of disk space is not available, so I added a new hard disk. How can I tell SQL Server to start using disk space from the new drive.

Comment: Dettach database, move it to another disk, and re-attach.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189133.aspx

Comment: Is your data data-file and log data-file(s) on different spindles (harddrives) ?

Comment: Whilst SQL Server can use multiple files for a single database, there's more planning required around it than just "use the next hard disk"

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest instead that you just move the database to the new, bigger drive. In addition to avoiding the complexity of splitting your database across multiple drives, you also free up disk space for the other databases that will stay on the original disk.

First, execute the following:

```
USE yourdb;
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile;
```

In most cases you should get two rows here, one for the data file, one for the log file (you can tell which is which by the `usage` column). You'll want to make note of the values in the `name` column for substitution below.

Then, in a period of downtime:

```
BACKUP DATABASE yourdb TO DISK = 'newdrive:\somepath\yourdb.bak' WITH INIT;
GO
RESTORE DATABASE yourdb WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, 
  MOVE 'data_file_name' TO 'newdrive:\datapath\yourdb.mdf',
  MOVE 'log_file_name'  TO 'newdrive:\datapath\yourdb.ldf';
```

This is a little more work but a lot safer than detach / attach. Primarily because if something goes wrong with the restore, you still have the backup and/or the original database. If something goes wrong during the attach, you have 0 copies of your database.